# Connect front-end with back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I trying to build project where user can buy product.
All my routes on server side are working. (Register, login, fetch data from mongo, fetch single product). I would like to send price data from single product page to server.
When I submit form, I am getting 404 error.

Here is console.log(err): xhr.js:247 POST http://localhost:5000/api/payhere/63c0f0cfef94663a27978c72 404 (Not Found)

Here is terminal err: POST /api/payhere/63c0f0cfef94663a27978c72 404 0.512 ms - 176

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks

React side:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   const x = price
  // console.log(x) ok
  
    try {

    let res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/payhere/${id}`, x)
    console.log(res)
 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response)
  }   
}
```

server side:

```
app.post('/api/payhere/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let x = req.body
    console.log(x)
})
```

Comment: Hard to tell not seeing the other routes. I guess the login endpoint is also an app.post? What is the difference? Also on app.post... the async seems odd. Have you tried curl or Postman to test the endpoint?

Comment: I found my mistake, instead of x I should used object and insert x to object. let res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/payhere/${id}`, { x } )     when I worked on it next time, terminal did not show mi err: POST /api/payhere/63c0f0cfef94663a27978c72 404 0.512 ms - 176   , but show mi emptpy object {}   weird!!